# how to create context menu when right clicking on marker on a map using angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: angularjs, gis, angular-leaflet-directive

I am new to angular-leaflet-directive.

I want to have a context menu when i right click on a marker.

I couldn't find any examples in angular way.

Can anyone please guide to achieve it.

Is that functionality exists in angular-leaflet-directive ?, because I couldn't find anything about in the documentation.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?

Comment: @BalkrishanNagpal ya, i have done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first download required files for angular context menu from this [link](https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.contextmenu/tree/master/dist)

here is the example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoapp">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
  <script src="   leaflet.contextmenu-src"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.contextmenu.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.css" />
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("demoapp", ["leaflet-directive"]);
    app.controller('MarkersSimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.showCoordinates = function(e) {
        alert(e.latlng);
      }

      var mainMarker = {
        lat: 51,
        lng: 0,
        focus: true,
        draggable: true,
        message: "hey marker",
        contextmenu: true,
        contextmenuWidth: 140,
        contextmenuItems: [{
          text: 'Show coordinates',
          callback: $scope.showCoordinates
        }]
      };
      angular.extend($scope, {
        london: {
          lat: 51.505,
          lng: -0.09,
          zoom: 8

        },
        markers: {
          mainMarker: angular.copy(mainMarker)
        },
        position: {
          lat: 51,
          lng: 0
        },
        events: { // or just {} //all events
          markers: {
            enable: ['dragend']
              //logic: 'emit'
          }
        }
      });
      $scope.$on("leafletDirectiveMarker.dragend", function(event, args) {
        $scope.position.lat = args.model.lat;
        $scope.position.lng = args.model.lng;
      });
    }]);
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MarkersSimpleController">
  <!-- <leaflet lf-center="london" markers="markers" height="480px" width="100%"></leaflet> EVENTS WILL STILL FIRE but all will for each directive-->
  <!-- NOTICE events attribute is optional it is more for options in whitelisting (enable), blacklisting (disable), and logic (emit or broadcast)  -->
  <leaflet lf-center="london" event-broadcast="events" markers="markers" height="480px" width="100%"></leaflet>
  <h1>Markers simple example</h1>
  <p>Initial marker position (lat/lng): <strong ng-bind="markers.mainMarker.lat"></strong> / <strong ng-bind="markers.mainMarker.lng"></strong></p>
  <p>Actual marker position (lat/lng): <strong ng-bind="position.lat"></strong> / <strong ng-bind="position.lng"></strong></p>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/eAsBXYeOvrvrplkv0cBd?p=preview) for the same